# React apollo taking data from cache

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am working on web app, to fetch data I am using `React-apollo-graphql`, So I have two buttons on my UI to fetch two data, So when I click on one button I am fetching some data and same for button 2.

But when I click again on button1 it is taking data from cache memory, I know this is best for fast UI update / rendering.

**My issue**

Now suppose I have updated my data in my DB so that data will not show on UI until unless I do page refresh.

So this the thing which is troubling be a lot now.

I doing this

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
uri:
    'my Uri',
cache: new InMemoryCache(),
```

});

Comment: If you need to react on EXTERNAL (DB, other user/client) data changes you can use polling or subscriptions - fetching policy "network only" or "no cache" can be not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change [fetch policy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#optionsfetchpolicy) it is better to change it for each request separately, but you can change it globally for the whole application

```
const [fetch, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(QUERY, { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' });

// globally
const client = new ApolloClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        query: {
            fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: What does this useLazyQuery do, I am using useQuery and useMutation

Comment: @dheerajkumar Requests data if necessary, example `<button onClick={fecth}>Fetch</button>`.

Comment: `useQuery` request data at the first render, not on click. How do you use it to request click data?

Comment: I do by managing the states, in hooks now will use this.

Comment: Hey I tried using this lazyquery it is fine but issue is when i click button and run that fetch that time I want to have data, so I am consoling data initially when page loades it says undefined and when I click it says data, is this correct way ?

Answer (score 3):

To Globally disable the cache and rely only on the network data -

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        query: {
            fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
        },
        watchQuery: { fetchPolicy: "no-cache" },
    },
});
```

To fetch the data here are two ways and the fetch policy is optional and depend upon your use case -

1- With `useQuery`

```
const { data, loading, refetch } = useQuery(QUERY, { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' });
```

Here the `refetch` can be used again to pull the data - with simple `refetch()`

2- With `useLazyQuery`

```
const [getData,{ loading, data, refetch }] = useLazyQuery(QUERY, {fetchPolicy:'network-only'});
```

Now with `useLazyQuery` we can trigger the call on demand whenever needed - `getData()`

Comment: what does this watchQuery do ?

Comment: The <Query /> React component uses Apollo Client's watchQuery function. To set defaultOptions when using the <Query /> component

Answer (score 2):

You can set the "no-cache" as an extra option to pass when you instantiate your client.

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: {
    watchQuery: { fetchPolicy: "no-cache" },
    query: { fetchPolicy: "no-cache" },
  },
})
```